# Will using UNIX_TIMESTAMP() slow down my INSERT query

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

I have to make over 20 insert statements in one go. I am using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` there to insert seconds since epoch in my time columns.

My php timezone is `UTC`

So should i use `$time = time()` for inserting values or `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is fine.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html

Answer (score 1):

[time()](https://www.php.net/time)

> time — Return current Unix timestamp

[UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

> If called with no argument, returns a Unix timestamp (seconds since
> '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC) as an unsigned integer.

Looks to me they are the same thing. So I highly doubt there would be a difference noticable enough to warrant choosing one over the other just for optimization. Choose whichever makes your code easier to read and understand would be my suggestion. MySQL can handle a very large number of actions at once so doing something trivial like getting the timestamp would be almost instantaneous.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, **decide based on functionality, not on efficiency**; you probably won't even feel the difference, even with 100 insert statements.

Which option to choose should depend on your functional requirements:

1. If you must absolutely be certain that the value for each statement is the same, you should   "cache" the value of `time()` and use that to do the insert; btw, this can be done either in MySQL or PHP (see below).
2. For all else, choose whatever you like.

If you are inserting multiple records, I hope you would consider prepared statements; doing so may actually speed up the insert statements in a more significant way, mainly thanks to the less amount of data that has to travel between code and database. For example:

```
SET @time = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
PREPARE stmt FROM 'INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (@time)';
EXECUTE stmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be inserting a billion rows and it's going to take you the whole day to insert it, and you really really want to avoid the timestamp being a problem, ask whomever the data is for if it's ok if you insert all rows with the same timestamp. Then use a single generation of the timestamp, put it in a variable, and use that for all insert statements as the value. This way you run less code each insert. But that's up to whomever the data belongs to if they're happy with it :)